# Determine if a Method is a `RemotableViewMethod`

Tags: java, android, reflection, remoteview

I am building a Widget which contains a ProgressBar. If the Widget is computing I set the visibility of that ProgressBar to `VISIBLE`, and to `INVISIBILE` if all computings stopped. There should be no Problem, because the `setVisibility` is documented as  `RemotableViewMethod`. However some guys at HTC seem to forget it, (i.e on the Wildfire S), so a call to `RemoteViews.setVisibility` will result in a crash. For this reason I try to implement a check, if `setVisibility` is really callable. I have writen this Method for it:

```
private boolean canShowProgress(){
        LogCat.d(TAG, "canShowProgress");
        Class<ProgressBar> barclz = ProgressBar.class;
        try {
            Method method = barclz.getMethod("setVisibility", new Class[]{int.class});
            Annotation[] anot = method.getDeclaredAnnotations();
            return anot.length > 0;
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            LogCat.stackTrace(TAG, e);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            LogCat.stackTrace(TAG, e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

This will work, but is *REALLY* ugly as it will return `True´ if *ANY* Annotiation is present. I looked, how RemoteView itself is doing the lookup and found this:

```
if (!method.isAnnotationPresent(RemotableViewMethod.class)) {
                throw new ActionException("view: " + klass.getName()
                        + " can't use method with RemoteViews: "
                        + this.methodName + "(" + param.getName() + ")");
            }
```

But i could't do the same, because the Class `RemotableViewMethod` is not accsesible through the sdk. How to know if it is accesible or not?

Comment: Hey! Do you think this is something you might be able to answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36679333/android-notification-remoteview-settranslationx-for-textview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Writing my question I had the Idea to lookup for the class by its Name, and it worked.
So I updated my Method to the following:

```
private boolean canShowProgress(){
        LogCat.d(TAG, "canShowProgress");
        Class<ProgressBar> barclz = ProgressBar.class;
        try {
            Method method = barclz.getMethod("setVisibility", new Class[]{int.class});
            Class c = null;
            try {
                c = Class.forName("android.view.RemotableViewMethod");
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return (this.showProgress= (c != null && method.isAnnotationPresent(c)));


        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            LogCat.stackTrace(TAG, e);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            LogCat.stackTrace(TAG, e);

        }
        return false;
    }
```

which works flawlessly